# No contact information returned

Tags: gazebo-1.4, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As can be seen from the picture below there is obviously a collision. However no contact information is returned.

At the beginning of collision a lot of data returned, but after the system gets to equilibrium contact information is not longer available.

Is it a bug or I have to tune some simulation parameters? Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks,

Boris

[image: image description]

---

**EDIT**: Here are [model](http://pastebin.com/5wKf4SZK) and [world](http://pastebin.com/vm3c7SKk) SDFs.

I just noticed that there is a solver of type `quick` in my world. Can it be the cause?

**EDIT #2**: Tried Solver type `world`, but now I am unable to spawn any objects from gui - Gazebo simply dies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1478/no-contact-information-returned/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-21**:
Hi, are you getting the contacts from messages, or you have your own plugin? If it is a sensor, then seeing the sdf file might also help.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-02-21**:
I have my own plugin, but `$ gztopic echo /gazebo/default/physics/contacts` also shows nothing (except for time).

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-21**:
In your plugin is the sensor active?   ( 'this->parentSensor->SetActive(true);' ) But I suppose yes, if you said you get the data at the beginning.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-02-22**:
Yeah, sure, it is active.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-07**:
Inactive objects get automatically disabled. This will stop collisions from being reported.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-03-09**:
@nkoenig, so what triggers them back to active? Thanks.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-14**:
there is a <allow_ auto _disable> tag in within  that you can set to false. You can give this a try

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-17**:
An active object that collides with an inactive object will make the inactive object active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A model without links will become inactive when it reaches a resting state.

You can disable this behavior on a per-model basis using the <allow_ auto _disable> tag in within .

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2511/wei/) on 2016-03-25**:
should be like this:

<allow_auto_disable>false</allow_auto_disable>
....